# Change default attribute for routes path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello again stackoverflowers!

I want to create links but not using the default `:id` attribute, I would like for example

```
article_path(@article)
```

to generate

```
/articles/example-article
```

instead of the default

```
/articles/1
```

Bonus, I would like to make `articles` the default controller. I achieved this using:

```
root 'articles#index'
get ':name' => 'articles#show', as: 'article'
```

This works fine, but `article_path` still generates the id link

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but when you wrote your `get` line, did you remember to remove the `resources :articles` line as well?

Comment: yes, there is no `resources :articles`

Comment: actually, there is `resources :articles` inside `namespace :admin`, I don't think it should cause any interference

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm not certain, sadly, as I can't test anything at the moment. Try doing a `rake routes` in your console and seeing which route(s) is/are claiming the `article` path name, and which one is first in the list. Remember that routes are executed in the order they appear in the routes file.

Comment: there is only `article GET /:name(.:format) articles#show`, that is correct haha

Answer (score 1):

Try the friendly id gem:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

It is a powerful gem, I used in my old project.

have a look the following railscast to learn more about it

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Comment: Hey :) friendly id is a great gem, I read about it and its powers, but it requires ActiveRecord and I do not have it (I'm using MongoDB with mongoid gem)